# Byte conversion fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

I have a problem with Python's `&` bitwise operation:

```
>>> x = 0xc1
>>> y = 0x7f
>>> x & y
>>> 65
>>> bytes([65])
>>> b'A'
```

The problem is the conversion from decimal to hex. `65` is `0x41`, however Python says that it is `'A'`. Why?

Comment: Why are you using `bytes` if you want `hex`? `hex(65) == '0x41'`... Also, note that your problem is **not at all** with the `&` operator, which is giving the expected result (`65`).

Comment: bytes() will convert to ascii. use hex() as above.

Comment: Do you just want to print the hexadecimal value?

Comment: Searching on google I saw they use bytes... Thank u very much, u saved my life :)

Comment: `bytes()` isn't converting to ASCII, it's just storing the 65 as the number 65. It's `bytes.__repr__` that does the conversion to ASCII later, representing each byte that corresponds to a printable ASCII character as that printable ASCII character.

Comment: only for python3 I guess

Comment: Thank u guys. I was using bytes function because I want to concat the result of `base64.b64decode(coded_string)` with one more byte at the end. If I use hex() it doesn't work. Any help? (Sorry if i'm asking obvious questions, I started with python few days ago)

Comment: If you _want_ a byte, that's _exactly what you already have_. `b'A'` is one byte. You're done.

Comment: Tahnk u guys, Finally I see it! U are great ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The value that you already have is exactly the value you want. From a comment:

> I was using bytes function because I want to concat the result of base64.b64decode(coded_string) with one more byte at the end.

`bytes([65])` creates a `bytes` object with a single byte with the numeric value `65`. What that number means depends on how you interpret the bytes.

The fact that its `repr` happens to be `b'A'` isn't relevant. What the value actually is, is the one byte you want. But the `repr` of a `bytes` object, as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) explain, uses the `bytes` literal format for convenience. Any byte that matches a printable ASCII character gets represented as that character, a few common values get represented with backslash escapes like `\n`, and anything else as a hex escape, all within `b'…'`

So, `repr(bytes([65]))` is `b'A'`, because byte `65` is the printable ASCII character `A`.

---

If you want to get a string with the hexadecimal representation of the number `65`, you can use the [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) function—or, if you want more control over the formatting, the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) function:

```
>>> hex(65)
'0x41'
>>> format(65, '02x')
'41'
```

But that's not what you want here. You want the value `b'A'`, and you already have that.

Answer (score 1):

65 is not A in hex, it's A in [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/); `print(bytes([65]))` and `print(chr(65))` outputs `b'A'` and `A`, respectively (ASCII representations). [Hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) is merely a numeral system with 16 as its base. 0x41 is therefore `4 * 16^1 + 1 * 16^0 = 65`.

Comment: This is pretty obviously a Python 3 question—otherwise `bytes([65])` would be `'[65]'`, not `b'A'`—so this Python 2-specific answer is misleading.

Comment: @abarnert: Updated the answer to comply with python >= 3.